# How to get opcodes of a c program

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, opcode

I know how to get the assembly code of my program using gdb but how do I get the opcode?
I need it to hack a linux server (don't worry it's part of a class I'm having so no real server will be harmed). Actually I was reading [this](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) article and I'm wondering how can I get from assembly:

```
[aleph1]$ gcc -o shellcodeasm -g -ggdb shellcodeasm.c
[aleph1]$ gdb shellcodeasm

(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x8000130 <main>:       pushl  %ebp
0x8000131 <main+1>:     movl   %esp,%ebp
0x8000133 <main+3>:     jmp    0x800015f <main+47>
0x8000135 <main+5>:     popl   %esi
0x8000136 <main+6>:     movl   %esi,0x8(%esi)
0x8000139 <main+9>:     movb   $0x0,0x7(%esi)
0x800013d <main+13>:    movl   $0x0,0xc(%esi)
0x8000144 <main+20>:    movl   $0xb,%eax
0x8000149 <main+25>:    movl   %esi,%ebx
0x800014b <main+27>:    leal   0x8(%esi),%ecx
0x800014e <main+30>:    leal   0xc(%esi),%edx
0x8000151 <main+33>:    int    $0x80
0x8000153 <main+35>:    movl   $0x1,%eax
0x8000158 <main+40>:    movl   $0x0,%ebx
0x800015d <main+45>:    int    $0x80
0x800015f <main+47>:    call   0x8000135 <main+5>
0x8000164 <main+52>:    das
0x8000165 <main+53>:    boundl 0x6e(%ecx),%ebp
0x8000168 <main+56>:    das
0x8000169 <main+57>:    jae    0x80001d3 <__new_exitfn+55>
0x800016b <main+59>:    addb   %cl,0x55c35dec(%ecx)
End of assembler dump.
```

the following:

```
testsc.c
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
char shellcode[] =
    "\xeb\x2a\x5e\x89\x76\x08\xc6\x46\x07\x00\xc7\x46\x0c\x00\x00\x00"
    "\x00\xb8\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80"
    "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcd\x80\xe8\xd1\xff\xff"
    "\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x89\xec\x5d\xc3";
```

The system is linux x86 and the language I will be using C. I'd really like an automated way, but a manual solution would work too.

I mean how do I convert %ebp, %esi, %esp etc.. Is there a map I can use? or an automated programm?

Comment: Are you looking for an x86 disassembler?

Comment: I think the disassembler does the opposite of what I'm trying to do

Comment: A listing of the x86 instruction set has the mappings, it can be used to disassemble 0xEB (which is `JMP`) or vice versa (assembling, or "compiling", `JMP` to 0xEB etc).

Comment: Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: What is more how do I convert, say <main+47> to opcode?

Comment: Any decent overview of the instruction set explains the various addressing modes etc. But if all you care about is the end result, you just need an assembler. `gas` I believe is included in the GCC suite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! First disassemble then type :
x/bx hit enter and get one by one the hex representation of the assembly commands!

Comment: You can do it all at once by using x /100bx start_address

That will give you the hex representation of the next 100 bytes starting from start_address. Change 100 to the number of bytes that your disassembled code spans.

Answer (score 12):

Here you go:

```
Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <shellcode>:
   0:       eb 2a                   jmp    2c <shellcode+0x2c>
   2:       5e                      pop    %esi
   3:       89 76 08                mov    %esi,0x8(%esi)
   6:       c6 46 07 00             movb   $0x0,0x7(%esi)
   a:       c7 46 0c 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0xc(%esi)
  11:       b8 0b 00 00 00          mov    $0xb,%eax
  16:       89 f3                   mov    %esi,%ebx
  18:       8d 4e 08                lea    0x8(%esi),%ecx
  1b:       8d 56 0c                lea    0xc(%esi),%edx
  1e:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
  20:       b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  25:       bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
  2a:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
  2c:       e8 d1 ff ff ff          call   2 <shellcode+0x2>
  31:       2f                      das
  32:       62 69 6e                bound  %ebp,0x6e(%ecx)
  35:       2f                      das
  36:       73 68                   jae    a0 <shellcode+0xa0>
  38:       00 89 ec 5d c3 00       add    %cl,0xc35dec(%ecx)
```

Note how the last 00 in that `add %cl` instruction comes from the string null terminator byte; it is not explicit.

How I got this was that I simply compiled your declaration with

```
gcc testsc.c -c
```

and then

```
objdump -D testsc.o
```

Comment: That may be so, but the answer is the same. You can disassemble that `shellcodeasm` program using `objdump` instead of doing it inside `gcc`. As you can see, the output format gives you the disassembly listing *and* the opcodes. You can do some text processing to cut out the column of bytes and automatically transform them into a C declaration.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
gcc -S -c tst.c -o -
```

or

```
gcc -g -ggdb -c tst.c
objdump -S tst.o
```

to get the disassembly of your program with the opcodes.

To get the disassembly of your char array, you can use:

```
gcc -c tst.c
objdump -D -j .data tst.o
```

Comment: Are you sure? objdump won't disassemble data section by default and gcc won't convert arbitrary literal strings to opcodes.

Comment: @zvrba updated my answer, I didn't notice at first he wanted the disassembly of the array bytes.

Comment: If objdump won't disassemble data sections by default, how I did produce that answer?

Comment: @Kaz `-S` as `-d` only disassembles `.text` but `-D` disassembles the other sections too.

Comment: The GNU binutils `objdump` does not disassemble any section by default. In fact, by default, it prints a help screen.

Comment: `gcc -c tst.c && objdump -S tst.o` worked for me on Linux 2.6.32-5 and gcc 4.7.1. But just doing `gcc -S -c tst.c -o -
` without the `objdump`-step only produces the assembly mnemonics on my system, not the opcodes

Answer (score 0):

Create a small assembly file, say `code.s`.  Then put the following inside:

```
.text
.byte 0xeb, 0x2a, 0x5e, ..
```

Assemble it with `as code.s -o code.o` and use objdump to disassemble the result.